# What does RUN yes | mean in a docker file?

Tags: linux, docker, command, pecl

I'm not great at Docker and trying to learn a little more.

What does the **RUN yes |** *blah blah blah*  mean? I found it on the web when trying to fix docker and xdebug, which I'm still not finished doing but to fix it I have to start understanding more of the underlying components of how Docker is supposed to work.

This page (frustratingly) has NO information about it: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

[image]

Comment: IIRC yes outputs "yes" or "y" repeatedly, thus answering all "continue y/n" questions of the following commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a command (has nothing to do with docker) that basically confirms any commandline questions, see the manual:

https://linuxhint.com/bash_yes_command/